# Scale @SqsListener from spring-cloud-aws 3.0.0

Tags: java, amazon-sqs, spring-cloud-aws

Trying to consume from SQS as fast and reliable as possible using the [@SqsListener](https://docs.awspring.io/spring-cloud-aws/docs/3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/index.html#sqslistener-annotation) annotation.

Here is my code:

```java
@SqsListener(value = "${sqs-url}", maxConcurrentMessages = "${maxConcurrentMessages:30}", 
maxMessagesPerPoll = "${maxMessagesPerPoll:15}", pollTimeoutSeconds = "${pollTimeoutSeconds:5}")
    public void listenEvent(List<Message<String>> messages, BatchAcknowledgement ack) {
        var successfullyProcessed = new HashSet<>();
        // https://docs.awspring.io/spring-cloud-aws/docs/3.0.0/reference/html/index.html#batchacknowledgement

        messages.forEach(message -> {
            try {
                // ... my logic ....

                successfullyProcessed.add(message);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Failed message={}", message, e);
            }
        });
        ack.acknowledge(successfullyProcessed);
        log.info("Acknowledged {} messages", successfullyProcessed.size());
    }
```

extra config for manual acknowledge:

```java
        //...
        // https://docs.awspring.io/spring-cloud-aws/docs/3.0.0/reference/html/index.html#acknowledging-messages
        factory.configure(options -> options
                .maxDelayBetweenPolls(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
                .acknowledgementMode(AcknowledgementMode.MANUAL) 
                .acknowledgementInterval(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
                .acknowledgementThreshold(10)
                .acknowledgementOrdering(AcknowledgementOrdering.PARALLEL));
```

I believe maxConcurrentMessages is the number of threads to run in parallel, but not sure. If it is, Then don't want to have that number to high as I have limited CPU. Problem is that maxMessagesPerPoll cannot be higher than maxConcurrentMessages and therefore I cannot do polls for 100 messages using 8 threads. How can I make this efficient using low maxConcurrentMessages?

Comment: Have you tried to do it without Spring?  I've scaled to many threads reading from a single SQS queue and can get very good throughput.

Comment: Was trying to avoid doing custom code, but probably will have to do it for performance reasons. Reading https://docs.awspring.io/spring-cloud-aws/docs/3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/index.html#default-polling-behavior doesn't help as I don't see how batches are handled.

Comment: Hi @la00, was your task cpu bound or IO bound? If it is IO bound, why can't you set the maxConcurrentMessages to a higher limit like 100 as most of the threads will be waiting for the response like how tomcat does?

Comment: It was IO, but still with all configs it was slow. I wrote some complex code where I have only 1 thread polling, but if there's many messages I scale to a limit number of threads. I would expect the lib to work like this, but It think they have a coordinator thread that poll and distribute to others, but was not fast enough for me.

Comment: Try making it asynchronous with `@Async`.